# How to use filter function in python 33

Tags: python, list

I'm now start learning python and I'm have problem with filter function.

If I run

```
list=list(range(10))

def f(x): return x % 2 != 0

print(((filter(f,list))))
```

I will get the result is

```
filter object at 0x00000000028B4E10

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And if I modify the code to

```
list=list(range(10))

def f(x): return x % 2 != 0

print(list(filter(f,list)))
```

The result I get will be

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Vo Quang Hoa/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/Hello.py", line 6, in <module>
     print(list(filter(f,list)))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What's happend. How to get the list 1 3 5 7 9
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you called your `list` variable, um, `list`.  You must not use the same name as other objects!  Call your list something else, and/or use a naming convention like upper camel case;

```
Fred=list(range(10))

def f(x): return x % 2 != 0

print(list(filter(f,Fred)))
```

Comment: The Python PEP 8 style guide advices you use lower_case_with_underscores for local names instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: true (sorry, that should be True).  That would result in `list` if you only have one word in your name, whereas `List` would not collide with a builtin.  But I agree that would be horribly confusing.

Comment: In *normal* code you probably can come up with much better names than `list`. In this case, perhaps `range_list` would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

You renamed `list`, giving it a different value. Don't do that, you shadowed the built-in type. Change your code to use a different name instead:

```
some_list = list(range(10))

def f(x): return x % 2 != 0

print(list(filter(f, some_list)))
```

and then `filter()` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help to you

```
ran=range(10)

def f(x): return x % 2 != 0

res = filter(f,ran)

for i in res:
   print(i,end=' ')
```